# Understanding Climate

Tags: internal-consistency, climate

So climate is a pretty confusing subject, I've been searching for a very generalized map of climates. I wanna post it hear for some questions regarding this map
[image]

http://www.geocurrents.info/place/australia-and-pacific/australias-climatic-anomalies

**Is this generalized map accurate?**

Comment: With no scale on the axis is pretty hard to call that drawing a map.

Comment: @L.Dutch, it goes from pole to pole, it doesn't need a scale as it's proportional and also fairly approximate.

Comment: @Separatrix Thank you for addressing that, I fell asleep. But yea just pole to pole I doubt a scale is needed

Comment: You need to specify the latitude on the map, and at least the radius of the planet to get a feeling of the extension of the continent. Without those info we can just give wild guesses. Hint: the tropic position depends on the axial tilt.

Comment: @L.Dutch I've been doing research on the topic and now the second part of the question has been removed. Now the question is in your opinion is this very generalized climate map accurate?

Comment: That looks like a pelvic girdle.

Comment: Scale is also needed in order to be able to determine the width of the continent, which is important in order to determine how arid the eastern side of the continent would be. Also, note that this scheme does not take mountain ranges into account.

Comment: It's reasonably plausible for a continent which is mostly flat and not extremely wide; that's why it's used in a schoolbook. High and long mountain ranges will distort the climate map beyond recognition, especially in they are oriented north to south. If the continent is extremely wide (think Eurasia) then there will be a vast desertic area in the middle no matter what.

Comment: There's clearly a mountain range on the western edge of the continent, otherwise the steppes and desert there don't make sense

Answer (score 1):

As a generalized map, sure it is accurate enough. Is it realistic? Not really, but that isn't the point of this map. The hypothetical continent shows ideal climates (as stated in the article you link to) as a learning tool. Real world climates are not ideal, nor are continents symmetrical. This continent also conspicuously lacks any large bodies of water on it or mountain ranges, both of which can significantly affect regional climate.